# How to filter an nested ICollection List in c# with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Consider following class structure:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class ItemSet
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getItemSet("B2");
        }

        static public ItemSet generateCompleteItemSet()
        {
            Item item1 = new Item();
            item1.ID = new Guid();
            item1.Type = "A1";
            Item item2 = new Item();
            item2.ID = new Guid();
            item2.Type = "B2";
            Item item3 = new Item();
            item3.ID = new Guid();
            item3.Type = "B2";

            ICollection<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            items.Add(item1);
            items.Add(item2);
            items.Add(item3);

            ItemSet itemSet = new ItemSet();
            itemSet.ID = new Guid();
            itemSet.Items = items;

            return itemSet;
        }

        static public void getItemSet(string type)
        {
            ItemSet completeItemSet = generateCompleteItemSet();
            ItemSet filteredItemSet = completeItemSet;
            filteredItemSet.Items = completeItemSet.Items.Where(item => item.Type == type); 
        }

    }
}
```

Tested with:

- Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition
- Console app (.NET Framework) Template

Questions:

- How can i get an result ItemSet with all Items that have a specified 'Type' Attribute within the 'getItemSet' function?
- The 'getItemSet' will not compile because "where" delivers an IEnumerable but i need an ICollection.

Comment: From what? Please provide a [mcve], ideally with input data, expected output, what you've tried so far and what happened.

Comment: I've added an Example.

Comment: You haven't added a [mcve] though, have you? Can I copy/paste/compile/run that code? No. Likewise, you haven't shown what you've already tried or what went wrong.

Comment: Getting better, although it's still not complete - I can't copy/paste/compile/run... it sounds like all you're missing is a called to `ToList()` after your `Where` call though. (`List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`.)

Comment: Edited the Question again, even if you've got already the answer for it. But i am curious if this fulfil all requirements to be a good Question :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

(EDIT - added both all items and filtered items as `List<Item>`)

```
//test data
List<Item> itemsList = new List<Item>();
itemsList.Add(new Item() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Type = "a" });
itemsList.Add(new Item() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Type = "a" });
itemsList.Add(new Item() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Type = "b" });
itemsList.Add(new Item() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Type = "c" });

List<ItemSet> itemSetList = new List<ItemSet>();
itemSetList.Add(new ItemSet() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Items = itemsList });

//select all items
var allItems = itemSetList.SelectMany(i => i.Items).ToList();
//filter items by type
var filteredItems = itemSetList.SelectMany(i => i.Items.Where(x => x.Type == "a")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, i've edited the Question in the meantime. Sadly the Items are not in a List but in an ICollection. Ok Nvm, .ToList() seems to be the Solution.

Comment: @The_Holy_One well, is this solution useful to you? `List<T>` implements `ICollection` interface, so you shouldn't have problems..